# 20.04 - Is there a way to add Google Search Bar to Desktop?

Tags: search, google, widgets

I have checked the old questions but they were really old and solutions as "screenlets" doesn't work anymore. How can I have a simple google search box on status bar or on desktop as we have on android?
Thanx in advance.

---Thank you for suggestion. Problem is (almost) solved. I couldn't get chance to turn on "Google Search" extension anyway. But I have installed another extension with name "Google Search Provider". It is active. And now when I click "Super" button to search in my softwares, It does search also on google too. I hope this solution also helps someone.---

Comment: I am confused is this a question or an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gnome Google Search extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1057/google-search/) can do what you want.

Please note that neither the layout or the underlining workflow is identical to Android's but it's close enough.

Old solutions like the one mentioned in the question were applicable to Unity DE only. Ubuntu current runs Gnome DE and Gnome Extension is the typical way to add functionalities to the desktop.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. I have checked now "Gnome Google Search extension" page. There was a toggle says "OFF". I tried to turn it ON but now instead of toggle there is ERROR word and I can't click anymore.

Comment: You need to click the links to learn the instructions to activate and use (user) Gnome Extensions in Ubuntu as such usage is not enabled by default.

Comment: I have visited extensions from my softwares and also from there I cannot turn the google search toggle on.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation For chrome or Firefox you need to install the same package. And yes, please use the one or the other to enable extensions. You can also use the links for each "app store" to install browser addons that take you to the Gnome extensions with just one click, very convenient.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Problem is (almost) solved. I couldn't get chance to turn on "Google Search" extension anyway. But I have installed another extension with name "Google Search Provider". It is active. And now when I click "Super" button to search in my softwares, It does search also on google too. I hope this solution also helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I did it my way: Install U Launcher for Linux,then go to startprograms,disable U Launcher and add a new entry with:  env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/ulauncher

Now you will have a searchbar like Google Searchbar at start.But unfortunetly it will disappear,when you do other things on desktop.

Comment: If I read this correctly this an X11 only answer?

Comment: probably not @David, wayland supports x11 and that's what he does here. He instructs wayland to use X11 for it.